# Filter items of same Type from another list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my class,

```
public class App
{
   public string Appname;
   public string Appcode;

}
```

I have a list of apps like

```
List<App> apps;
```

another list of same object like

```
List<App> filteredapps;
```

now i need to filter from the first list which has the same app names from the second list.
how can i achieve this

Comment: Please, provide and example of the first list, the second and the expected result.

Comment: Do you want Intersect, or Except? Your question is not clear. Please provide example input and output. (MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apps.where(a=>filteredApps.Select(fa=>fa.AppName).Contains(a.AppName))
```

OR

```
var filteredNames = filteredApps.Select(fa=>fa.AppName);
apps.where(a=>filteredNames.Contains(a.AppName))
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use Enumerable.Intersect Method :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx

```
void Main()
{
    List<App> apps;
    List<App> filteredapps;

    var query=apps.Intersect(filteredapps,new AppComparer());


}
public class App
{
   public string Appname;
   public string Appcode;

}

class AppComparer : IEqualityComparer<App>
{

    public bool Equals(App x, App y)
    {

    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;


    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
        return false;


    return x.Appname == y.Appname && x.Appcode == y.Appcode;
}

// If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects  
// then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects. 

public int GetHashCode(App product)
{
    //Check whether the object is null 
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(App, null)) return 0;

    //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null. 
    int hashProductName = product.Appname == null ? 0 : product.Appname.GetHashCode();

    //Get hash code for the Code field. 
    int hashProductCode = product.Appcode.GetHashCode();

    //Calculate the hash code for the product. 
    return hashProductName ^ hashProductCode;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = apps.Where(x=>filteredapps.Any(y=>y.AppName == x.AppName));
```

if you want a `List` instead of an `IEnumerable`, add `.ToList()` at the end of the query.